# Как автоматически монтировать

Tags: linux

Каким образом можно автоматически монтировать разделы fat-ntfs из windows при загрузке-перезагрузке, чтоб, например, когда включение ПК, разделы автоматически монтировались, а при выключении - размонтировались. Например, через скрипт или какой другой способ.

Система CentOS 6

P.S

```
    /dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root /                 ext4    defaults              1 1    UUID=37964b09-7ce0-4b97-b4b6-00e7b77767dc /boot ext4    defaults              1 2    /dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_home /home             ext4    defaults,user_xattr   1 2     /dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_swap swap              swap    defaults              0 0    tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults              0 0    devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620        0 0    sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults              0 0    proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults              0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/fstab` - правильно править руками.

Вот пример строки монтирования FAT32:

```
/dev/sda1       /mnt/diskC  vfat    rw,user,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866,defaults,umask=0    0 0
```

"что монтируем" "в какую папку монтируем" "с какой файловой системой" "параметры" 0 0предпоследняя цифра принимает значение либо ноль, либо единица - это что-то связанное с архивацией, в смысле бакапа. Последняя цифра - может быть 0, 1 или 2 - флаг того - проверять ли файловую систему утилитой fsck: 0 - не проверять, 1 - указывается на рутовую файловую систему, проверять, 2 - остальные файловые системы, которые надо проверять.

вот пример того, как указывать "что монтируем" в виде UUID-идентификатора:

```
UUID=E81A-1A1C  /mnt/win/hda5   vfat    codepage=866,iocharset=utf8,umask=0 0 0
```

Для NTFS:

```
UUID=1A248EA2248E810D   /mnt/win/hda1   ntfs-3g locale=ru_RU.utf8,umask=0 0 0
```

Для файловой системы ntfs-3g - обязателен установленный пакет ntfs-3g. Просто ntfs - есть пакете samba. Также в "параметры" можно прописать идентификаторы uid и gid (указывается либо имя либо число), под которыми будут создаваться файлы и папки на файловой системы, а также читаться под этими идентификаторами.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, проще всего обойтись без скриптов и воспользоваться утилитой pysdm:    sudo apt-get install pysdmЗатем зайти в меню: Система -> Администрирование -> Storage Device Manager и выбрать нужный раздел для монтирования![монтирование][1]При настройке убедиться, что выставлен флаг "The filesystem is mounted at boot time":![настройки][2]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2NBS.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0tGx.png

Comment: yum install pysdm  *****  *****  *****  Skipping filters plugin, no data  0 packages excluded due to repository protections  Setting up Install ProcessNo package pysdm available.  Error: Nothing to do    P.S есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Автор не указал, что используется GUI. Стандартная установка подразумевает отсутствие графического интерфейса.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/fstab

**Дополнено**.

В /etc/fstab пишем, например

```
/dev/sdb5       /opt/storage3   ntfs    gid=nobody     1 1
```

(nobody - группа юзеров под каким нужно монтировать). Пакет ntfs-3g обязателен.

Comment: Подробнее можно,пожалуйста. Нужно добавить три раздела созданные в Windows   2-NTFS и 1-FAT  config добавлю в вопрос  Заранее спасибо

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.