# Автоматическое монтирование дисков в Linux

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте! Не могу сделать так, чтоб диски монтировались автоматически. На одном форуме советуют как сделать это, но у меня не работают некоторые команды. Может кто с нуля объяснит это дело? Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [Как автоматически монтировать...](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/1161/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как автоматически монтировать...](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/339668/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1):

в консоле vim /etc/fstab сделать запись что и куда монтировать + опции